# Visual Studio Short cuts using Mac Keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcuts, visual-studio, c#

I am having trouble coding in visual studios with my mac keyboard as some of the short cuts wouldn't work, notable the "Go to Definition" which is set as <kbd>F12</kbd>.

I tried to change the shortcut for this but somehow it doesn't identify any key I input using mac keyboard.

Can someone please advise how I can overcome this problem.

P.S. I am using visual studio 2013 in Parallels Desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you troubleshoot this problem, there are two things to consider as "filters" between your keyboard and your Windows instance. Those are *OS X* and *Parallels*.

That is to say, if a keystroke isn't getting through to windows, it is being "caught" by one of those layers, and you need to figure out which layer is the problem.

The first thing to check is your Mac's System Preferences, under Keyboard. There is a checkbox that designates the F keys to be used as function keys or as media keys--make sure this is set for standard F keys. This may actually solve your problem since you mentioned trouble with F keys specifically.

For the Parallels layer, you just need to be aware that Parallels will catch certain keyboard inputs for its own use, but these typically won't collide with windows shortcuts. These would be configured in Parallels preferences.

Lastly, a good diagnostic tool for this kind of problem would be to use a keyboard viewer that shows you what keys the system sees as being pressed on the Mac and on the a Windows system. You could use that to figure out where your keystrokes are being caught.